# javascript real-time update from 1 text area to multiple textarea

Tags: javascript

I want to have 1 main textarea where you can type anything and it will, in real-time, update on multiple textareas showing the typed letters in different fonts.

example:
Main text area:

```
<textarea id="textField0" autocomplete="off" style="font-family:'Alex Brush';" 
onkeyup="javascript:setFontText(this.value);" rows="2" name="textField0"></textarea>
```

Multiple text area:

```
<textarea id="Courier new" class="fontTextArea2" style="font-family:courier_newregular;" 
autocomplete="off" name="Courier new"></textarea>

<textarea id="Arial Black" class="fontTextArea2" style="font-family:arialblack; " 
autocomplete="off" name="Arial Black"></textarea>
```

How do i go about writing javascript for setFontText()?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function setFontText(text) {
   document.getElementById("Courier_new").innerHTML = text;
   document.getElementById("Arial_Black").innerHTML = text;
}
```

I would also suggest you change your `id`s to something that doesn't contain white spaces.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lq0ykyk/1/

Answer (score 0):

Ive taken the event handler from inline to javascript, Just make the font's you want in css

```js
var areatwo=document.getElementById('two');
var areathree=document.getElementById('three');
 
  
    document.addEventListener('keydown',setFontText);
document.addEventListener('keyup',setFontText);
      
      function setFontText(){ 
            var textareavalue=document.getElementById('one').value;
                areatwo.value=textareavalue;
                  areathree.value=textareavalue;
      
  }
```

```css
#two{font-family:courier_newregular;}
#three{font-family:arialblack; }
```

```html
<textarea id="one"></textarea>
<textarea id="two"></textarea>
<textarea id="three"></textarea>
```

Comment: I wasn't the one that downvoted. Your way seems cleaner but i was just looking for some crude to work with html and avoiding the css.  Thanks for the input though!

Comment: my one seperates the style, script and html whereas the one above leaves them all intermingled, not good practice